# When the dock covers a window the icons on the dock are not selectable

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, dock

When the dock covers a window the icons on the dock are not selectable. How this should work is that the dock icons should take presidence over whatever is underneath the dock. Or possibly the window should avoid going under the dock but every time you maximize the window it underlays the dock.

[window interferes with dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jlXc.png)

In the attached image the window is under the dock and i can no longer select the dock icons and instead the interface selects from the window.

Is this a bug? Is there a fix?

EDIT: add system information

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

inxi -GA
Graphics:
Device-1: NVIDIA TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] driver: nvidia
v: 460.91.03
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nvidia
unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.91.03

Comment: Please state your Hardware `inxi -GA` and your Ubuntu Version. **Edit** your answer and paste/write the infos into your question

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it occurs not when maximizing the window but after coming from standby or something - all old maximized windows get under the dock.